# Create pagination for custom post types in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have an events page which I would like to add pagination to. However, with it being a custom post type I am finding it rather difficult. I have managed to get pagination working for my news page, but I cannot get the same result for the events page. Here is my code for the events page

```
<?php
get_header();
get_sidebar('left');
?>
<article class="content-main events" role="main" id="post-<?php the_ID() ?>">
<?php include 'breadcrumbs.php'; ?>
<?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>'2')); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
        <div class="news-post">
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>
            <?php the_excerpt() ?>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<!--Pagination-->
    <?php echo paginate_links( $args ) ?>
    <?php
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
    ?>
</article><!-- //.content-main -->
<?php

get_footer();
```

If I try to change this

```
<?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>'2')); ?>
```

to this

```
<?php query_posts(array('category_name'=>'events','posts_per_page'=>'2')); ?>
```

This doesnt work either. However, if I remove the line altogether, it shows up the news post types. I am stumped!

Comment: the "events" category belongs to the post type taxonomy right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pagination for custom post types should work the same as normal posts.

If you take a look at the default theme [TwentyEleven](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentytwelve) you can see how they do it.

Basically they use **next_posts_link()** and **previous_posts_link()** functions.

You can look at that in functions.php > **twentytwelve_content_nav();**

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

you need to add global $paged and then in your array that is being passed to WP_Query you need to add 'paged' => $paged

">

```
<?php 
global $paged;
$temp = $wp_query;
                    $wp_query = null;

                    $wp_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'yourcustomepost','posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged ) ); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
        <div class="news-post">
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>
            <?php the_excerpt() ?>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<!--Pagination-->
    <?php echo paginate_links( $args ) ?>
    <?php
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
    ?>
</article><!-- //.content-main -->
<?php
```

Comment: You are brilliant! Not had much experience with Wordpress so thank you! I have one last query, it only shows the first page. The 2nd page brings up a 404 error :/

Comment: Change 'posts_per_page' => 2 to 'posts_per_page' => 10 or any number you want. Make sure you have proper permalink structure, That might be   issue for 404 error

Comment: Yeah I understand how to show more. I have currently 4 events, 3 per page. When I use the pagination links it shows an error.

Answer (score 0):

just replace below function in functions.php file
note: in backend setting->reading->post per page : set this value to one

```
function twentyeleven_content_nav( $html_id ) 
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
        <nav id="<?php echo esc_attr( $html_id ); ?>">
            <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
            <div class="nav-previous">
                <?php next_posts_link( __( ' Previous', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
                <?php
                    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts where post_type='post' and post_content<>''" );

                    for($j=1;$j<=$count;$j++)
                    {
                        echo "<a href='?paged=$j'> $j < </a>";
                    }
                ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Next', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
            </div>

        </nav><!-- #nav-above -->
    <?php endif;
}
```